# Google webmaster tools:We were unable to connect to your server. (site verification)

Tags: dns, domains, google-search-console

I have a shared webhotel that has three domains.
Only one of them can be verified through webmaster tools.

All domains are though live and working websites but can't be verified.

I've checked DNS with pingdom and all seem to be fine and there's no difference between domains.

What could be wrong? I understand that it is just a matter of Google to "download" frontpage and check metatag? Why it fails to verify whilst website is indexed into search?

Comment: What is a "shared webhotel"?

Comment: Bad word choice

Answer (score 2):

Always make sure your website has web pages that return the HTTP status 200 code (which means the result is an actual page).

What I do for site verification with google webmaster tools is follow it's recommended method:

> 1. Download this HTML verification file.  [google2da9166c91fd3e7e.html]
> 2. Upload  the file to http://example.com/
> 3. Confirm  successful upload by visiting  http://example.com/google2da9166c91fd3e7e.html  in your browser.
> 4. Click  Verify below.
>
> To stay verified, don't remove the HTML file, even after verification succeeds.

To complete step #2, you need to download the file presented to you which in this example is google2da9166c91fd3e7e.html, then upload the file to your document root folder on the server and change the permissions on the file so that the world has at least read access to it.

To complete step #3, visit the URL shown and you'll see text similar to the following in your web browser:

```
google-site-verification: google2da9166c91fd3e7e.html
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize my site was serving, but with a 500 status code!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I think that this problem is solved.

Site is in maintenance mode and returns 503 of which google of course thinks that is not worth verifying.